# What vagrant really is

Tags: vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I'm puzzled by vagrant because I can't understand what it really is.

As we all know, if we want to run another system in our current system, we must install virtualbox and the mirror of that system such as CentOS.

When I installed vagrant it required virtualbox, so it can't be another virtualbox.
I thought it may be a system management just like bower but the vagrant box homestead which contains mysql, nginx, redis, php and memcache is just over 600M which is less than the smallest Linux system..

So I'm very confused. Could you tell me what the vagrant really is?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Vagrant website](https://www.vagrantup.com/about.html):

> Vagrant is a tool for building complete development environments. With an easy-to-use workflow and focus on automation, Vagrant lowers development environment setup time, increases development/production parity, and makes the "works on my machine" excuse a relic of the past.

Basically Vagrant allows you to easily set up a virtual development environment. Everybody can build and configure pre-packaged environments called *boxes* and publish them for others to use. One of those boxes being homestead.

Here's an article that explains it more in-depth: [What is Vagrant and Why should I care?](http://24ways.org/2014/what-is-vagrant-and-why-should-i-care/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Vagrant website](https://www.vagrantup.com/)

> Create and configure lightweight, reproducible, and portable development environments.

Instead of just installing your software requirements, Vagrant installs a whole development environment with similar hardware and software setup. So you never have to bother with your software not working on some other hardware during development.